# How to convert Dolby Vision HDR to HDR10+?

Tags: hdr

I'd like to convert a file recorded from an iPhone 12 to a royalty-free version (for upload to Wikimedia, Flickr, etc). So the transfer involves:

| Source (iPhone proprietary-encumbered) | Destination (royalty-free) |
| --- | --- |
| 4k 60fps (UHD, not DCI) | 4k 60fps |
| BT.2020 in HLG (WCG) | BT.2020 in HLG (WCG) |
| Frame-level dynamic HDR metadata in Dolby Vision profile 8.4 | Frame-level dynamic HDR metadata in HDR10+ |
| HEVC | VP9 (open to AV1 as well but that's likely more nascent) |
| Bitrate is 31 Mb/s | Fine with higher bitrate to maintain same SSIM/PSNR |
| Audio is in AAC | Audio to Vorbis/OGG |

According to https://codecalamity.com/encoding-uhd-4k-hdr10-videos-with-ffmpeg/ it should be possible to do most of this.
Anyone can help me cook up the right command for this?

Comment: Can you share the sample file, say via dropbox? I can assist

Comment: @DennisMungai here you go! https://github.com/sagz/files/releases/tag/v0.1

Comment: I'm currently investigating a solution based on `libplacebo` for this, will report back with findings.

Comment: any luck, @DennisMungai? :)

Comment: Still investigating, looking into the ffmpeg build for Jellyfin. `libplacebo` seems like a dead end on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sadly no](https://www.reddit.com/r/hometheater/comments/eholm5/dolby_vision_to_hdr10_conversion/), not without expensive specialist broadcast processing hardware.

From the Reddit link,

> Dolby Vision is 100% proprietary. There is no incentive at all for
> Dolby to convert anything to HDR10+ to help out Samsung users (and
> pre-2019 Panasonics) when the only reason HDR10+ exists is because
> Samsung didn’t want to pay Dolby for the license.
>
> Dolby Vision is simply an enhancement layer on top of HDR10 which is
> the base layer. There are a couple types of DV layers. The MEL
> (minimum enhancement layer) and the FEL (full enhancement layer) which
> reconstructs the original 12-bit signal. The FEL is what gives DV a
> large advantage over HDR10 and HDR10+.
>
> Page 12:
>
> https://www.dolby.com/us/en/technologies/dolby-vision/dolby-vision-for-creative-professionals/dolby-vision-uhd-bluray-authoring-workflow.pdf